# Close handling in finally block

Tags: java

Is the code part in the finally block well handled or should I do it in another, more cleaner way.

```
 private TestClass() throws Exception { 

       Statement stmt = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       Connection conn = null;

       try {
            // Codeblock
         }
         } finally {
                try {
                       if (rs != null)
                             rs.close();
                       if (stmt != null)
                             stmt.close();
                       if (conn != null)
                             conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                       // Logging;
                }
         }
}
```

Comment: This isn't real code, merely stub code, so it's going to get closed.

Comment: Its easy to correct to real code by removing the `}` unfortunately edits must at least be six characters. All who *put on hold* are disrespectful to the essence of the question, hey is at least one good answer! I am disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

A try-with-resources block could simplify your code:

```
try (Connection conn = ... ;
     Statement st = ... ;
     ResultSet rs = ... ;) {

     // Codeblock
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}
```